# Transfering Data from Multiple HTML Files into Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Suppose I have a number of HTML documents, each of which has the same format.  While the information in these documents is not in tables there are always specific key words that give away where the desired information is located.  Is there a way to set up a macro so that Excel searches each of these documents for a specific 'title', returns all characters after the first white space of the title, and stops only once it reaches two white spaces in a row?  The idea would be to then place all of this information into one column and begin the process again with another 'title'.  I am really not sure where to start with such a macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should get you close

```
MyPath = "path to folder containing HTML files"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set my_files = fso.getfolder(MyPath).Files

For Each f1 In my_files
    Set TxtStream = fso.OpenTextFile(path_fname, ForReading, False, TristateUseDefault)    
    my_var = ""

    Do While Not TxtStream.AtEndOfStream
         my_var = my_var & TxtStream.ReadLine   
    Loop

    TxtStream.Close

    pos_1 = instr(1, my_var, "your Title")
    pos_2 = instr(pos_1, my_var, "  ")
    my_txt = mid(my_var, pos_1, pos_2 - pos_1)
   ' do whatever with the captured text
Next
```

Comment: I seem to be having an issue getting my loop to execute, do you have an example of a loop that would run for around 2000 files?

Comment: Are all of your HTML documents located in a folder and are they the only files in the folder?

Comment: Yes - apologies for the late response - my main issue is having Excel recognize these files.  I tried to automate the import wizard without much luck, as it only seems to recognize XML files and not HTML files unless I explicitly change to "All Files", I'm not sure how to do via macro.

Comment: Thank you ron, I will take some time to go over that tonight!